# QGIS with CSV file, incorrect coordinates

Tags: geolocation, geometry, coordinates, shapefile, qgis

I'm working on a QGIS project and adding layers from CSV files.  I can Add Delimited Text Layer, then save the layer as a shapefile, making sure I've selected Latitude and Longitude correctly as y and x.  But whether I specify Lat as y and Long as x or vice versa, the point shows up in the same place, in the Galapagos Islands, not Chicago as it should be.  I'm using the correct Geometry CRS for the project.

Comment: can you provide some sample data of your csv?

Comment: I solved the issue by closing and re-opening QGIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved: The problem resolved itself when I closed and re-opened QGIS.